# Azure AD Authentication for the known email address

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I have successfully integrated the azure AD to my MVC application and it works as expected.

```
    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
       {
           ClientId = ADClientId,
           Authority = ADauthority,
           Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
           {
               RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
               {

                   if (context.Request.Path.Value == "/Account/ExternalLogin" || (context.Request.Path.Value == "/Account/LogOff"))
                   {                           
                       string appBaseUrl = context.Request.Scheme + "://" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.PathBase;
                       context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = appBaseUrl + "/";
                       context.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = appBaseUrl;
                   }
                   else
                   {                           
                       context.State = Microsoft.Owin.Security.Notifications.NotificationResultState.Skipped;
                       context.HandleResponse();
                   }
                   return Task.FromResult(0);
               },
           }
       });
```

Now, I have a new request - I should be able to send the email address to the azure authentication site so that it will skip the first step and directly take to the password window for the email address that being passed.

Is there any attribute in the openidconnect -c# that i can setup with the email address?

Comment: You need to set the `login_hint` query parameter on the redirect. Not sure how you did that with OWIN :)

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48544880/use-login-hint-with-openid question help?