# Use login_hint with OpenID

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, openid, openid-connect

I am trying to add the `login_hint` to the OpenID sign-in request for Azure AD authentication.

It is not working for me, to add `login_hint` as a property:

```
var properties = new AuthenticationProperties();

properties.RedirectUri = "someCallbackUrl";

properties.Dictionary.Add("login_hint ", "SomeUsername");

AuthenticationManager.Challenge(properties, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
```

Adding the login_hint manually to the query string `...&login_hint=SomeUsername` at least proves to me, that such functionality exists :-)

I understand that if I were to use `GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider` that I would have to override itself [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24957152/1405376). Is something similar needed for the approach that I am trying to take?

Comment: Hmm is this using the OWIN middleware?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It turns out that I had to add the `RedirectToIdentityProvider` to `app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication`:

```
Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
{
    RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
    {
        string login_hint = context.OwinContext.Authentication.AuthenticationResponseChallenge.Properties.Dictionary["login_hint"];
        context.ProtocolMessage.LoginHint = login_hint;
        return Task.FromResult(0);
     }
}
```